# How to Re-register instance in AWS Target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there a way I can re-register the target in target group without doing normal process.

```
Hi All,

I created a Target Group (Name: New-Target) and New-Target has 2 Instances registered (Instance_1 and Instance_2). For some reason, I deregistered Instance_1 and now only Instance_2 is being tagged to target group.

Where can I find deregistered instance (i.e., Instance_1) so that i can re-register without doing normal process. 

Thank you.
```

Comment: What is "normal process". Your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: Normal Process means by Clicking on Register targets, selecting the Instance and registering them.